# Сигнатура функции file в PHP

Tags: веб-программирование, php, файлы, функции

В php есть функция `file`, возвращающая массив строк текстового файла. В книге Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web-приложений на PHP и MySQL" в одном месте приведено использование функции file с аргументом - указателем на файл

```
$fp = fopen("$DOCHMENT_ROOT/../orders/orders.txt", "r");
$filearray = file($fp);
```

а в другом месте использовалась в качестве параметра - путь к файлу

```
$orders= file ("../. . /orders/orders.txt" ) ;
```

Какой параметр принимает эта функция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только путь к файлу можно передать. Есть кстати отличная документация на русском языке, вот пример страницы документации:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php